# Error transfering "Arithmetic: Underflow"

Tags: runtime

[image: Example transfer]

In the example above, we try to transfer 1 TFT from Eve to Dave. This extrinsic fails with Underflow error. When I looked at the error description I found: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/115af33fc4aa62052eb52a757bce80db0a13bcad/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/misc.rs#L91-L93

"There has been an underflow in the system. This is indicative of a corrupt state and likely unrecoverable."

This error only showed up when upgraded our network to use polkadot-0.9.42. Is this related to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12951 ? Because when I upgrade both accounts, the issue still resides.

This is on our development network where we accidently ran this migration twice: https://github.com/threefoldtech/tfchain/blob/864ea673258360e22b79dc3acf9e3ece48e5ef27/substrate-node/runtime/src/migrations.rs#L33.

Comment: I found the issue, it seems like our `totalIssuance` on our network is 0. This check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1d1351114df9fc7e123cf34220e3d8ce39f8a1f0/frame/balances/src/impl_fungible.rs#L109 was added I think. Because of this check, our development network seems to have been broken even more as it was already broken it seems. Is there a way to set this `totalIssuance` to some value without a migration?

Comment: Althought, this value was not 0 a few days / weeks ago. We could still transfer tokens in this period before it started failing. This suggests that the total issuance slowly dropped over time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct this could result from a transfer which is `>=` than the [`total_issuance`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6d19bc2d15f96fe513671568ec66e8b21aaed031/frame/balances/src/impl_fungible.rs#L110) or [`total_supply`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6d19bc2d15f96fe513671568ec66e8b21aaed031/frame/assets/src/functions.rs#L173) of the native currency or an asset, respectively (conversion to `Arithmetic` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6d19bc2d15f96fe513671568ec66e8b21aaed031/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/misc.rs#L115)).